# AngularJS uncatchable error in unit tests $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test an example similar to the button click / focus example on this Angular page: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

However, when I try to catch the error using expect(...).toThrow(), the error is being thrown anyway.

Here is a plunker with an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/26wogXb2xv4dxUthM2n8

```
  $rootScope.clickSecond = function() {
    span[0].querySelector('[second]').click();
  }

  var span = $compile("<span><button first ng-click='clickSecond()'>Dismiss</button><button second ng-click='fail=true'>Fail button</button>")($rootScope);
  function clickButton () {
    span[0].querySelector('[first]').click();
  }
  expect(clickButton).toThrowError(/inprog/);
```

When I wrap the programmatic clicks in angular.element(...).click(), this test does work. However, the specific library I'm testing that is triggering the events does not use jQuery or angular to do so.

Any hints on why I can't catch the exception? You can see the exception appear in the console. Why does it work with the jqLite wrapper?